# Paypal REST Api for Paying another paypal account

Tags: python, paypal

I'm looking into the new paypal REST api.

I want the ability to be able to pay another paypal account, transfer money from my acount to their acount. All the documentation I have seen so far is about charging users.

Is paying someone with the REST api possible? Similar to the function of the mass pay api or adaptive payments api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment, paying another user via API is not possible via REST APIs, so mass pay/Adaptive payments would be the current existing solution. It is likely that this ability will be part of REST in a future release.